# jQueryDataTable : Column Names are not shown in jquery data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, jquery-ui

```
success: function (data) {
                    $('#datatable').dataTable({
                        "bProcessing": true,
                        "bPaginate": true,
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                        "aaData": data.aaData,
                       // "columns": data.aoColumns,
                        "aoColumns": [
                        { "mData": "Server_Name" }, 
                        { "mData": "Primary_Administrator" },
                        { "mData": "Secondary_Administrator" },
                        ]
                    });
                    }
                });
```

I am trying to display server processed data in jquery data table. I am not exactly getting how to display column names against data.I tried several ways like defining a server side structure with aoColumns but it didn't worked. Also this application uses Asp.Net framework. Please note that I have columnnames coming from server side which might change so I have empty HTML table. I havent predefined column names using html table.

Server Side structure is like this :-

```
var result = new
                {
                    iTotalRecords = totalRows,
                    iTotalDisplayRecords = totalRows,
                    aaData = excelDataList,
                    aoColumns =  columnsList,
                };

                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                js.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
                Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(result));
```

Server Side class is as follows :-

```
public class XYZ
{
    public string Server_Name { get; set; }

    public string Primary_Administrator { get; set; }

    public string Secondary_Administrator { get; set; }
}
```

My Html code :-

```
<body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table id="datatable">
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Sample Json :-

```
{
    "iTotalRecords": 42,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 42,
    "aaData": [{
        "Server_Name": "FS",
        "Primary_Administrator": "Mic",
        "Secondary_Administrator": "An"
}],
    "aoColumns": [{
        "sTitle": "Server_Name"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "Primary_Administrator"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "Secondary_Administrator"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "F4"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "F5"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "F6"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "F7"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "F8"
    }]
}
```

Changed Json:-

```
"aoColumns": [{
        "sTitle": "Server_Name",
        "mData": "Server_Name"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "Primary_Administrator",
        "mData": "Primary_Administrator"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "Secondary_Administrator",
        "mData": "Secondary_Administrator"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "F4",
        "mData": "F4"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "F5",
        "mData": "F5"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "F6",
        "mData": "F6"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "F7",
        "mData": "F7"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "F8",
        "mData": "F8"
    }]
```

Comment: Can you please show your data structure.

Comment: i have edited the question with result data structure. I have a list of 'XYZ' class which has some variables holding data. Also column names are being given separetly in another list.Hope this helps!

Comment: One observation I made from lots of changes is that data table is displaying data properly with aoColumns. But how to display column names on top of that data is problem!

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Similar questions have been answered unsatisfactorily on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com also added sample json to get better idea.

Comment: I tried this way changing ajax call to this :- $('#datatable').dataTable(data); 
now its displaying column names but not data.

Comment: @user3168473 Are you getting any console errors in dev tools (f12 in browser)? Why do you have so many column names which don't have a corresponding data element? Is that what you meant by column names might change.. as in the number and the value of them?

Comment: That was in reference to aoColumns in the JSON response

Comment: I added mdata to the columns json and now it works fine.

Comment: You need to add mdata and the corresponding column names to get data and column names together finally solved it! Thanks for help!